# Having trouble with ES6 import / export variables

Tags: javascript, import, export, global-variables

I am trying to compare text from two HTML pages using javascript using two separate external js files and importing the needed variable to be compared. However the function is not showing any result.

My first html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <span id='current-name'>John Hamish Smith</span>
        <p id='new-billing'>0</p>
        <script src='experiment.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

experiment.js below:

```
const currentName = document.getElementById('current-name').textContent;
const newBillingField = document.getElementById('new-billing');
const currBillingValue = Number(newBillingField.textContent);
let newBillingValue = currBillingValue + 1;

import {nameCheck} from './test2';

const testing = () => {
    if(currentName === nameCheck) {
        newBillingField.textContent = newBillingValue;
        alert('hi there');
    } 
} 
window.addEventListener('load', testing);
```

then my second html is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p id='userName'>John Hamish Smith</p>
    <script src='./test2.js' type='text.javascript'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and test2.js as follows:

```
let nameCheck = document.getElementById('userName').textContent;
export {nameCheck}
```

However, even with the names being the same, my newBillingValue is still 0.
(the alert is just to facilitate the function test)

thank you!

Comment: That shouldn't be working at all, you should be getting an error at the `import` statement because the script tag has the wrong type; it should be `type="module"`. Are you using a bundler of some kind?

Comment: There are a couple of issues at first glance: To use modules in the browser you have to add `type="module"` to the `<script>` element (but maybe browsers autodetect this these days? idk). Assuming the import actually works, `test2.js` will be evaluated in the context of the first HTML page, which doesn't have an element with ID `userName`. The fact that there is another HTML page that also loads `test2.js` is irrelevant. You cannot communicate across two HTML pages this way.

Comment: Also, module specifiers on the web must include the file extension (`from './test2.js'`, not `from './test2'`) unless you're using an import map.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder I have updated both as you say. No bundler used no. Still do not have the function working though :(.

Comment: @FelixKling I see what you mean.. so as I do not have the element by id 'username' on the first HTML this will not work. In all honesty this is like the 3rd approach I try. I believe the most straight forward approach should be by using local storage but my local storage was not working and I could not fix it...